# ML.NET Regression FastTree predictions always return 0

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm trying to set up a sales prediction algorithm for a Sales Analytics application using ML.NET. I've just started learning ML.NET and did everything by the tutorials from Microsoft. 
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/Regression-SalesForecast

Here's the source model

```
public class SalesSummaryGeneralizedDTO
{
    public float ProductId { get; set; }
    public float SalesQty { get; set; }
    public float Day { get; set; }
    public float Month { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the prediction model:

```
public class SalesPredictionDTO
{
    public int SalesQty { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Main code:

```
var salesGeneralized = await _saleRepository.GetSalesForPeriod(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), DateTime.Now);

var mlContext = new MLContext();

var trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.ReadFromEnumerable(salesGeneralized);

var trainer = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTreeTweedie(labelColumn: DefaultColumnNames.Label, featureColumn: DefaultColumnNames.Features);

var trainingPipeline =
    mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("NumFeatures", nameof(SalesSummaryGeneralizedDTO.Day), nameof(SalesSummaryGeneralizedDTO.Month))
.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "CatFeatures", inputColumnName: nameof(SalesSummaryGeneralizedDTO.ProductId)))                
.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(DefaultColumnNames.Features, "NumFeatures", "CatFeatures"))
.Append(mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: DefaultColumnNames.Label, inputColumnName: nameof(SalesSummaryGeneralizedDTO.SalesQty)))
.Append(trainer);

var model = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);
var predictionEngine = model.CreatePredictionEngine<SalesSummaryGeneralizedDTO, SalesPredictionDTO>(mlContext);

var samplePredictionData = new SalesSummaryGeneralizedDTO
{
   ProductId = 7.0f,
   Day = 14.0f,
   Month = 12.0f
};

var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(samplePredictionData);
```

I provide as "Features" ProductId, Month and Day, and expect to see an estimate of SalesQty, but prediction always return SalesQty = 0.

Microsoft's docs didn't provide much help.
Thanks in advance for any advice on this!

EDIT:

Turns out Microsoft's tutorials are missing an important note, so the issue was with column mapping. While digging in the source code of one of the tutorials I've noticed that the prediction results column name is "Score", so now predictions are returning a value.
My "SalesPredictionDTO" has been missing an attribute, which i'll post below.
Also the tutorial's source code has no getter and setter for the Score mapped property, don't know if it's important or not, but it works.

```
public class SalesPredictionDTO
{
    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public int SalesQty;
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How much data do you have, and is it balanced? What metrics do you get, for your model?
Do Day and Month need to be categoricals, rather than numeric values?

Comment: @amy8374
I have a list of ~8k sale records; 

Metrics are: 
Average L1 Loss:    92.431;
Average L2 Loss:    23464.306;
Average RMS:          92.431;
Average Loss Function: 23464.306;
Average R-squared: 0.582;

Don't know about categorical and numeric, as i don't know what difference is between the two :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first scoring a test dataset with `model.Transform(someTestData)`, inspecting the transformed data, and evaluating the algorithm with `mlContext.Regression.Evaluate(transformedData)`. You can use `mlContext.Regression.TrainTestSplit(allYourData, testFraction: 0.1)` to split into a training and test set, or alternatively using the training set itself as a test set could be indicative but not best practice.

Only once you are satisfied with the prediction model that you have trained, I would start using the prediction function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It will definitely come in handy in the future.
I figured out what caused the initial problem, it was a mapping issue, i'll add that to my post.